# App preview video configuration in Final cut pro

Tags: ios, finalcut, app-preview

I created a view for `APP preview` in the App store. Here is my configuration in the final cut pro:

[Final cut pro screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpUu4.png)

But i got this error constantly

```
Your app preview is in the wrong format. For more information, see the Developer Help.
```

Then I found this website and I set this configuration there

https://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp4

Video bitrate: 10240

frame rate = 30

Audio Quality = 256

But I got the same error.

Then I bought this app in the Mac App store

https://apps.apple.com/de/app/app-preview-video-converter/id1137451860?l=en&mt=12

But the output video from this app got the same error as well.

I worked many hours on fix this problem, could anyone help me to how to save my app preview video?

Answer (score 1):

It seems theres a bug somewhere in App Store Connect at the moment. Your video format looks good so this must be what you are experiencing.

I am still waiting for it to be fixed and haven't had any success for at bit more than a day now - just checked again.

See related post on apple developer forums here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/120816

**Edit: It seems the error has been fixed now. Mine is working and so is it for the users on the related post**

Comment: I have the same issue since more than 24 hours now. It really seems to be a Bug currently on the App-Store connect. Screenshots upload well, but every Video (App-Preview) fails in the moments I click on save. Then I checked it with a other app which is in preparation, and I used even a month-old video I used already for another app - with success. Nothing works for the moment. Every Video in every format ends currently up with the message: "Your app preview is in the wrong format. For more information, see the Developer Help." - Hope Apple takes care soon... voilà

Comment: thank you so much for sharing your experience.  I was worry about my videos.

Comment: I confirm, that App-Preview video upload works again - nice!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem since yesterday. So I ended up submitting my app for review without the preview. Today it was reviewed and appeared in the App Store. I immediately went into iTC and instantiated a new version of the same app. Previously submitted screenshots showed up. I dragged the Preview video I had no luck submitting yesterday... and... it was accepted! With no error message!!! 
-_-;;

So here is the strategy you can use if you really want to submit the Preview:

1. Submit the current "unlucky" version for review. Optionally you can set it to be released manually.
2. Wait until it is reviewed and flagged as 'ready for sale'.
3. Instantiate a new version.
4. Add the Preview by dragging it into the screenshot drop area.
5. Archive, upload the new version; draw the rest of the owl.

Also make sure that the Preview you created meets the requirements.
Hope it helps.

Comment: It works now. Your workaround made sure time passed while it was being fixed.